# In GlassFish 5, EJB is not injected into Entity Listener

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish, eclipselink, java-ee-8

I'm currently working on a web app that uses Java EE 8 and GlassFish 5.

One of the app's entities has fileds that stores when the entity was created and modified the last time and by whom. This entity is annotated with an entity listener, that shall update these fields when the entity is persisted or merged.

```
@Entity
@EntityListener(CreatedAndModifiedListener.class)
public class MyEntity extends AbstractEntity {
    // AbstractEntity provides the ID field and equals(), hashCode() and toString()

    Instant createdOn;
    Instant modifiedOn;
    String createdBy;
    String modifiedBy;

    // Other fields
}

public class CreatedAndModifiedListener {

    @Inject
    UserService userService; // Stateless EJB

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void prePersist(Object o) {
        // Here, this.userService is null !
    }

}

@Stateless
public class UserService {
    public String getUser() {
        return "todo";
    }
}
```

After all, my code is quite similar to the code found at http://hantsy.blogspot.de/2013/12/jpa-21-cdi-support.html

When I run the app with GlassFish 5 and the entity is going to be persisted or merged, "prePersist()" is called as expected, but the EJB is not injected (userService is null).

I have reproduced this behavior with the converter example provided by hantsy (https://github.com/hantsy/ee7-sandbox/tree/master/jpa/converter), where a logger is injected into an entity listener. However, when I'm using hantsy's example with GlassFish 4.1.1, it runs as expected (the logger gets injected, no errors). When I use the example with GlassFish 5, it fails (NPE, because logger is not injected).

Am I missing an annotation or configuration to enable CDI for JPA 2.2? Or is this a bug in GlassFish 5 or Eclipse Link 2.7.0?

**Edit (2017-12-16):** I have updated Eclipse Link in GlassFish 4.1.1 to 2.7.0.v20170811. Now, GF 4.1.1 behaves the same. So, the behavior must be related to the current EL release.

Comment: Seems like https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/issues/21195 but with different versions. What eclipselink version are you using in gf 4.1.1?

Comment: I am using EclipseLink 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258, which was shipped with GF.

Comment: Try that one in Gf v5 then to see if it works.

Comment: Can you post UserService?

Comment: I have tried the other way around: Updated EL in GF 4.1.1 to 2.7.0.v20170811 (see edit in my question). Now, GF 4.1.1 behaves the same. However, I am building on Java EE 8 / JPA 2.2, so I cannot downgrade to EL 2.6.0.

Comment: Did you manage to eventually solve this?